# bz2 files compression question

Tags: compression, tar

When we compress a folder, we type the command tar -cjf folder.tar.bz2 folder, it compresses the entire folder into it.

Is there anyway to compress everything within the folder but the folder should not appear in the archive?

Example- when open the archive, the files within the folder will appear instead of the entire folder.

Answer (score 5):

Use -C parameter of tar

```
tar -C folder -jcvf folder.tar.bz2 .
```

I tried this in my PC and it worked ;)

Comment: I did that on the directory where the folder is, when i open the tar.bz2, it shows that everything is stored in . folder.

Comment: If you think this is the right answer, I'd be glad if you mark it so :)

Comment: just one more question. hehe. the files within the folder is stored in '.' folder when i open the tar.bz2.

Comment: "." folder is the folder you are in. So tar extracts the files to the folder where the tar xvf command is called.

Comment: what if I want all the files to be extracted separately without storing under a folder?

Comment: actually they are extracted separately to the folder you are in. Do not consider it as storing under a folder, think "." as a pointer to the folder you are in.

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
cd folder; tar -cjf ../folder.tar.bz2 *
```

The `*` at the end gets expanded by the shell to the list of all files (except hidden) in the current directory. Try `echo *`.

For hidden files, there are two possible approaches:

1. Use the `ls` command with its `-A` option (list "almost all" files, that is all except `.` and `..` entries for this and parent directory.

   cd folder; tar -cjf ../folder.tar.bz2 $(ls -A)
2. Use wildcard expressions (note that this doesn't work in dash, and, when any of the patterns doesn't match, you'll get it verbatim in the argument list)

   cd folder; tar -cjf ../folder.tar.bz2 * .[^.]* ..?*

Comment: yup, this works but what if i need to include the hidden files?

Comment: sorry for not mention about the hidden files earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're referring to is simply `cd folder; tar -cjf ../folder.tar.bz2 * .[^.]*`, but I could be wrong. This places the filenames at the top level in the resulting archive, as opposed to after `folder/`.

Comment: tried that. but i don' think it works.


tar -cjf folder.tar.bz2
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.

Comment: or is there anyway to select all the files within the folder? usually, if we do it within the folder, we append filenames that we want to compress.

Comment: I edited the response to add all files in the dir, including hidden ones.

Answer (score 0):

tar -jcvf folder.tar.bz2 folder/*